# Перемещение персонажа JavaScript

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Пишу онлайн игру. Сейчас используется перемещение персонажа на клетку по которой пользователь кликнул. Хочу сделать перемещение клавиатурой.

Как я это вижу:
Пользователь зажимает кнопку ходьбы - на сервер идёт запрос о том что пользователь начал движение, всем клиентам отправляется информация о том что игрок начал движение и на стороне клиента он двигается в определённую сторону, когда кнопку отпускает на сервер идёт информация что пользователь остановился. 
И вот здесь у меня проблема. Если у какого-нибудь клиента будет плохое интернет соединение, значит он может вовремя не получить информацию от сервера о том, что пользователь остановился и будет продолжать обрабатывать его перемещение до тех пор пока интернет не восстановится. Получается будет иметь неверную информацию о местоположении пользователя который сделал перемещение.

Что-нибудь сможете посоветовать?

Comment: Вряд ли с этим что-то можно сделать, но с этим можно жить, именно такие эффекты в играх и наблюдаются при потерях соединения. либо Вы на каждый чих делаете запросы на сервер и тогда все будет медленно, либо так как Вы описали

Comment: Передавайте состояние мира (дельтами, если надо) - кто, где, куда смотрит, куда движется и с какими скоростями и экстраполируйте на клиентах (если надо). Передавать инпуты - плохая затея. Инпуты хорошо передавать если у вас RTS и локстеп.

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, я вот тоже увлекаюсь разработкой игр и дал себе слово никогда не связываться с реалтаймом и физикой в своих играх. Не только потому что при плохом соединении с этим возникают проблемы, но ещё потому что даже мозги у людей работают не с одинаковой скоростью. Я против таких форм геймплея, когда для победы требуется быстрее жать на кнопки. Особенно когда речь идёт о мультиплеере. В моём представлении, идеальная соревновательная игра должна быть только пошаговой. Конечно, это лишь моя субъективная точка зрения и к вопросу она не имеет прямого отношения :)